# Android AChartEngine - How to rotate line chart label values

Tags: android, achartengine

Am working on an Android App which displays a line chart using AChartEngine. The line chart displays different values. Sometimes one of the value is mixed with others. In such a case, line chart value how to rotate. This doesn't look nice as you can see here:

https://docs.zoho.com/file/o319te5043ffa559d4aa0b5062026f90c3625

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
renderer.setXLabelsAngle(angle);
```

Comment: What explanation is needed to a method called setXLabelsAngle? It has some javadocs as well.